# Positioning in canvas

Tags: c#

I have matrix with dimensions matrix[height,width], that matrix is initialized with all 0, then im placing 4 which are acctualy some drawings(rectangles) in my canvas. Later i want to connect those drawing(rectangles) which are "4" via flat lines but for some reason my while loop stucks and wont end it. Here is my code im using, I hope this is enough for you to understand. I have defined coordinates for connection input and output.

```
public Point [] Again()
{
    Position startPosition = new Position(dockingStartPositionX, dockingStartPositionY);
    Position endPosition = new Position(dockingEndPositionX, dockingEndPositionY);

    List<Point> pointList = new List<Point>();
    Position currentPosition = startPosition;
    //Ne zeli mi izac iz ove while petlje jer dode do pozicije di je tablica i onda tamo zapne ali ne bi trebalo, trebalo bi svejedno krenut dalje
    while (true)
    {
        if (currentPosition.x == endPosition.x && currentPosition.y == endPosition.y) break;

        List<Position> directions = new List<Position>
        {
                new Position(currentPosition.x +1,currentPosition.y),
                new Position(currentPosition.x -1,currentPosition.y),
                new Position(currentPosition.x ,currentPosition.y+1),
                new Position(currentPosition.x ,currentPosition.y-1)
        };

        double distance = Distance(currentPosition, endPosition);
        foreach (Position next in directions)
        {

            if (!OccupiedByTable(next))
            {
                double newDistance = Distance(next, endPosition);
                if (newDistance < distance)
                    currentPosition = next;

            }
        }
        pointList.Add(new Point(currentPosition.x, currentPosition.y));
        matrix[currentPosition.y, currentPosition.x] = 2;
    }
    Point[] points = pointList.ToArray();
    return points;
    }

        private bool OccupiedByTable(Position pos)
    {
        if (matrix[pos.y, pos.x] == 4)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
        private double Distance(Position pos1, Position pos2)
    {
        return Math.Sqrt((pos1.x - pos2.x) * (pos1.x - pos2.x) + (pos1.y - pos2.y) * (pos1.y - pos2.y));
    }
```

Comment: Put a break point on `currentPosition = next;` to see if it ever gets executed.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It executes. I know that because I have more than one case and it gets stuck on one case bc number "4" is one the way and i dont know why that would be problem bc it has 3 other dirrections to go